# Wireless frequently showing DNS errors while wired connection works fine on a TP-Link TD-W9980

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

This is a new issue that was not caused by any router settings changes that i'm aware of. I've had an extensive look and been completely overloaded by acronyms and talk of buffer bloat!

As soon as moderate traffic starts going through the wireless, all the devices remain "connected" but throw out name resolution errors. This was not an issue before and the number of devices has not changed, so i'm not sure whats causing the issue now.

The wired connection remains fine while the wireless is "down" and no errors appear in the router logs. I've seen people talking about overloading the wireless but it was a pretty expensive router and I'm only talking about 6 devices.

[Here are some results from a quick dslreports.com speedtest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLG8M.png)

The bufferbloat was fine through the download test but red (+300ms) throughout the entire upload test. I've also noticed that the connection information section on the router shows the upload to be a bit off but its been like that since the upgrade we received last year. We were without service for 12 days during the upgrade we weren't told about and rather than tempt fate I just let that issue lie rather than call BT again.

[Connection Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAwR8.png)

I'd greatly appreciate any ideas or suggestions and let me know if you need any further info.

Cheers,
John

Comment: Have you tried restarting your router?

Comment: If you are actually experiencing bufferbloat. There are a couple options. On your existing router try setting up QOS. You can try replacing your router with one that supports third party firmware (ddwrt, openwrt or asuswrt) they all can overcome bufferbloat issues. Pfsense/opensense also have fairQ quality of service which can overcome it. Regards,

Comment: Hey, yes I have restarted the router several times but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I think the buffer bloat issues likely stem from the upload rate issues more than the router, but if the router is the problem I will consider replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is a Confluence of 2 issues -

1. Your upload speed sucks - you should check with your ISP if they are caping it to 2megabit and get that fixed if possible - this is the root cause of your issue.
2. Something is using most of your bandwidth - are you sure your AP has not been compromised, and that none  of your computers are infected with mslware or p2p software?  To resolve the problem you need to find what is consuming all your outbound data.

Comment: Hey, Yea its likely that the upload speed is either capped or not functioning properly since the botched upgrade I mentioned before. I'm fairly confident Its not a virus related issue more of just a terrible bandwidth to begin with.

I will chase down BT and see about getting the upload problems resolved, hopefully that will have some effect on the other issues.